# Error: coc#_select_confirm requires complete_info function to work

Tags: python, vim

I'm using coc-nvim and coc-snippets for autocomplete and to create snippets, but appears this error.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue.  Upgrading to vim 8.2 fixed the problem for me.